# autoscrolling textview in android

Tags: java, android

I'm building a chat-like application that displays text the user inputs to the screen using a scrollview. What I'd like to do is making the scrollview autoscroll as more text is appended to the screen. 
I'm using a textview to display the input. The xml portion of the scrollview is as follows:

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttons"       
      >

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/start_chat"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

How do I go about doing that? I tried setting the layout's gravity to "bottom", but that doesn't work correctly (text inputed that moves up as the scrollview is scrolled down can't be viewed again).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can do it as well from `webview` and javascript! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scroll to the absolute bottom (where new TextView is added) use [fullScroll](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#fullScroll%28int%29) on the ScrollView when the TextView is added.

```
ScrollView my_scrollview = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroller);
my_scrollview.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

If instead you want to scroll relative from the current position the user is viewing, I would try something like [smoothScrollBy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollBy%28int,%20int%29) or [scrollBy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollBy%28int,%20int%29)

```
/* recently_added_textview being the TextView that was added to trigger this */
ScrollView my_scrollview = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroller);
int height = recently_added_textview.getHeight();
my_scrollview.smoothScrollBy(0, height);
/* x being 0 assuming you don't want to scroll left and right */
```

This way the user isn't sent to the bottom of the ScrollView if they're reading something around the top or middle.

Comment: This seems to work, although for some reason, because the keyboard is usually on screen while chatting, when the scrollview scrolls down it doesn't completely - the newest textview added is not displayed. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: @Malfunction Are you sure it's scrolling after the TextView is added and not before? If so, try Ramyle's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this after you added a new chat in your textview

```
scroller.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN if you want to scroll down
        //ScrollView.FOCUS_UP if you want to scroll up
        svComments.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```